# Angular Tour of Heroes HttpClient CRUD methods

Tags: angular, http, crud

I am currently learning angular with the Tour of heroes tutorial.
In the HTTP chapter, I dont understand how the corresponding heroes are called from the server, as it appears, there is only a url passed to the simulated server, for any of the HttpClient.get (or other CRUD) methods...

```
private heroesUrl = 'api/heroes'
```

and the corresponding get method for all Heroes (~array):

```
getHeroes (): Observable<Hero[]> {
  return this.http.get<Hero[]>(this.heroesUrl)
}
```

if return only one single Hero:

```
/** GET hero by id. Will 404 if id not found */

    getHero(id: number): Observable<Hero> {
      const url = `${this.heroesUrl}/${id}`;
      return this.http.get<Hero>(url).pipe(
        tap(_ => this.log(`fetched hero id=${id}`)),
        catchError(this.handleError<Hero>(`getHero id=${id}`))
      );
```

what will be returned from this url? I mean it is just a url, how is the database api connection reacting in the background in response to the url (or the id passed)?

same goes for other post methods:

```
addHero (hero: Hero): Observable<Hero> {
  return this.http.post<Hero>(this.heroesUrl, hero, httpOptions).pipe(..)
}
```

it has a url parameter, but how gets the actual hero passed to the server? and where is the hero id created?

Comment: Doesn't that example use the [in-memory API](https://github.com/angular/in-memory-web-api)? There is no server, it's all on the client. If you want to know how it's implemented, you could look at the source code.

Comment: And even if it was on the server, Angular doesn't care if it's a PHP script reading CSV from a file, or a Java servlet connecting to a relational database, or a NodeJS server reading documents from MongoDB. That's out of the scope of Angular, which runs in the browser, and gets data from a RESTful web service on a server.

Answer (score 0):

> what will be returned from this url?

When you perform an HttpClient.get, the result is always an observable. So you will receive an observable.

> I mean it is just a url, how is
>   the database api connection reacting in the background in response to
>   the url (or the id passed)?

As you can see in the `app.module.ts` :

```
 // The HttpClientInMemoryWebApiModule module intercepts HTTP requests
    // and returns simulated server responses.
    // Remove it when a real server is ready to receive requests.
    HttpClientInMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot(
      InMemoryDataService, { dataEncapsulation: false }
    )
```

> it has a url parameter, but how gets the actual hero passed to the
>   server? and where is the hero id created?

You can find more informations on 'how it works' here : https://github.com/angular/in-memory-web-api